# session_start() error: why it doesn´t recognize a new session?

Tags: php, session

I´m testing a php exercise, and I can´t get it working properly. It´s a counter that stores the visits inside a txt file as a simple integer. Every time I reload the page the number gets a +1.

Now, I want it to reload only when there´s a new visit, so I´m trying sesion_start() for the first time.

In class, this example worked just fine, but when I try to reproduce it at home, the number won´t change, even if I close the browser and open it again.

This is my code (it´s inside the php tags, naturally):

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION[contador]) {
    define('ARCHIVO', 'visitas.txt');
    if (file_exists(ARCHIVO)) {
        $fp=fopen(ARCHIVO, 'r');
        $cant=fread($fp,filesize(ARCHIVO));
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $cant=0;
    }
    $cant++;
    $fp=fopen(ARCHIVO, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $cant);
    fclose($fp);
    $_SESSION[contador]=$cant;
}
echo '<h3>Hay '.$_SESSION[contador].' visitas.</h3>';
```

Comment: I assume `contador` is a defined constant, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... erm... no? That´s all the code I´ve got, I replaced $contador with $_SESSION[contador]...

Comment: If you write this piece of code, you should know what is `$_SESSION[contador]`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, but last class whas the first time I´ve seen that function, and it seems that I didn´t quite understood it.

Comment: check your php ini parameter called `session.cookie_lifetime`. If different than 0, that's the reason.

Comment: Thanks Sebas! I thought that it could be related to php.ini. But it is  set session.cookie_lifetime = 0. I think Chrome doesn´t fully "stops" when you close the browser...

Answer (score 3):

contador should be in quotes unless it's a defined constant somewhere?? I assume it's a string

```
$_SESSION["contador"]
```

Try this out. It's different, but it'll do something at least. Would've posted as a comment, but I wanted code formatting.

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['contador'])){
    $_SESSION['contador']=1;
}else{
    $_SESSION['contador']++;
}
echo '<h3>Hay '.$_SESSION['contador'].' visitas.</h3>';
```

Comment: if the constant is defined, this answer is invalid.

Comment: Good advice but definitely not the problem. An `E_NOTICE` will be triggered however the undefined constant will simply resolve to the string `'contador'`

Comment: Well, even when the quotes info is correct, I´ve tried without quotes, with single quotes, and with double quotes. I think that´s because some weird Chrome browser thing, because it only works when I use the incognito mode... (it happens to me with Firefox too...)

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda First this is server side code so browser doesn't matter (generally). 

Second the code you provided starts with if(!$_SESSION[contador] which means that that code ONLY fires when that variable is NOT defined. Which means after the first time it runs it can never run again (until your session is cleared which is why incognito makes it work)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @Lenny is correct.  $_SESSION['contador'] is what is called a session variable or a variable assigned to the $_SESSION array.  So it MUST BE in quotes.  That is not optional.  And you cannot define a constant and use that value inside the brackets.

if you had a constant, you could set the session variable to that.  But, since your value is variable, as you are adding incrementally, it is by definition not constant.

Furthermore, refreshing your Web browser will keep your session active.  So if you truly want to test this, try session_destroy(); at some point.

Here is how this code will work (the storage of the session variable anyway):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
   define('ARCHIVO', 'visitas.txt');
   if(file_exists(ARCHIVO)) {
      $fp = fopen(ARCHIVO, 'r');
      $cant = fread($fp,filesize(ARCHIVO));
      fclose($fp);
   } else {
      $cant=0;
   }
   $cant++;
   $fp = fopen(ARCHIVO, 'w');
   fwrite($fp, $cant);
   fclose($fp);
   $_SESSION['contador'] = $cant;
}
echo '<h3>Hay ' . $_SESSION['contador'] . ' visitas.</h3>';
?>
```

Note: your logic is bad.  Your are telling your script that $cant is either equal to the value of the txt file OR it is equal to 0.  Then your are incrementing that value by one.  You will perform that task on each load.  You need to modify this code and finish your conditional statement.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])) {
   define('ARCHIVO', 'visitas.txt');
   if(file_exists(ARCHIVO)) {
      $fp = fopen(ARCHIVO, 'r');
      $cant = fread($fp,filesize(ARCHIVO));
      fclose($fp);
   } else {
      $cant=0;
   }
   $cant++;
   $fp = fopen(ARCHIVO, 'w');
   fwrite($fp, $cant);
   fclose($fp);
   $_SESSION['contador'] = $cant;
} else {
 $_SESSION['contador']++; 
}
echo '<h3>Hay ' . $_SESSION['contador'] . ' visitas.</h3>';
?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP's logic is fine.